# Express.JS url parameters aren't parsed

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following route configured

```js
app.put('/v1/users/:uid', function(req, res){
            res.send(req.route);
        });
```

When sending a PUT request to `http://localhost:3000/v1/users/blablabla`

I get the following output back

```json
{
   "path": "/v1/users/:uid",
   "method": "put",
   "callbacks": [
       null
   ],
   "keys": [
       {
           "name": "uid",
           "optional": false
       }
   ],
   "regexp": {},
   "params": []
}
```

As you see the *params* array seems to be empty instead of having the value "blablabla". But the "uid" key appears in keys, which I don't really know what to make of.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the trick is that Express uses [a sparse array to parse the params](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/d853c833f0d693ef0c0352ac3a02016701b6fe07/lib/router/route.js#L52).

When you pass it to `req.send`, the array is converted with `JSON.stringify`. Here's what happens in a JS shell:

```
> var params = [];
> params['uid'] = 1;
> params;
[ uid: 1 ]
> JSON.stringify(params);
'[]'
```

What's happening is that adding a non-numeric to an array does not change its length:

```
> params.length
0
```

So the new value is ignored by `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Laurent, thats not true. req.route prints the entire object representing the requested route. Just to clear it up, req.params is also returned empty for some reason. But the req.route.params key is supposed to contain the data by the docs: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route

Comment: You're right, I think I know what happened. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Already answered what makes it work but I'm not sure why the behavior is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the weirdest thing I've seen.

When doing a `console.log(req.params)` or `console.log(req.route.params)` I get an empty array response (`[]`).

But when doing a `console.log(req.params.uid)` I get the value! Thats extremely weird but hey, it works :)

Cheers.